# How does the 'value' keyword actually work in JavaScript, can we get a value and assign it at the same time?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I wandered a lot to understand this but cannot get any answer specifically related to my question, what i am trying to ask is that how does the 'value' key word returns the value of the textbox or any other element and we can assign at the same time.

we do not use parenthesis so that according to my understanding is not a function.

I am trying to create an object with a property, lets call it 'val' which will return the value and ill be able to assign a new value by using the equals to operator.

hard coded values work but how to get it dynamically? will i create a function which will fire every time a value is inserted and assign it to the property? or how will it work? because i cant clearly make it a function which returns a value because i wont be able to assign it then.

```
var searchBar = {
   element : document.getElementById('memSearchInput'),
   val : document.getElementById('memSearchInput').value.trim(),
 }
```

this clearly dosent work.

I havent posted many questions, so if this was not clear, sorry for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` here is not a "keyword", but a property of the DOM node returned by the `getElementById` call. Since you seem to be fetching an HTML `<input>` element there (which happens to be a DOM node object called [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)), you can find information on its `value` property right in that object'S description:

> Current value in the control.
>
> **Note:** for certain input types the returned value might not match the value the user has entered. For example, if the user enters a non-numeric value into an `<input type="number">`, the returned value might be an empty string instead.

You may have guessed by now that the property might return a string in many (but not all) cases, so your `trim` call will strip whitespace from start and end and the `val` property ends up being set to that very string - statically.

See [Working with objects: Defining getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) and the getter/setter pages linked from it for information on how to actually have control over what happens when you read a value from or write a value to the property.

Comment: that getters and setters is the thing i should be looking at, thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way built-in to set the value of an `input` or `textarea` and simultaneously get its original value.

But not to worry -- you can really easily write your own method to do so!

Here's one way:

```
function getAndSet(id, newValue){
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  var oldValue = el.value.trim();
  el.value = newValue;
  return oldValue;
}

var searchBar = {
  element : document.getElementById('memSearchInput'),
  val : getAndset("memSearchInput", "someNewValue")
}
```

Comment: i was asking for the theory behind how the thing works, wormbo's anwer is pretty much what i wanted :)